# How to share text on Android app?

Tags: android, facebook

I had my Android App to share text on social media that setup on the
device, every thing is OK with all apps expect the Facebook that it
isn't share any text.

**Code:**

```
public void share() { 
  String url = "http://www.elarabygroup.com/Calendar.apk \n"; 
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
  intent.setType("text/plain"); 
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url + contetView.getText());  intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ""); startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
}
```

Comment: facebook doesn't allow you to share `text` via share intent......... how ever you could do it by learning basics of their API system

Comment: @NitinMisra what about if i want to share only  String url = "http://www.elarabygroup.com/Calendar.apk \n";    on facebook

Comment: it's mentioned by developers at facebook that `AOSP` has bug which doesn't allow sharing of any `text` or `URL`